# Determining if certian properties of a topological space pass to its image under a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

> A property $P$ of topological spaces is said to "pass to quotients" if whenever $p : X \rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map and $X$ has property $P$ then $Y$ has property $P$. For the following properties determine if it "passes to quotients" or give a counter example.
>
> a. Compactness

Compactness passes to quotients, because $p$ is continuous and the image of a compact space (which is $Y$ in this case as $p$ is surjective) is compact.

> b. Simply connectedness

The continuous image of a connected space is connected, so $Y$ is also connected. To show that it is simply connected, we need to prove that $\pi_1(Y)=1$. However,  $p_{*}: \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y)$ is defined by $[\omega] \mapsto [p \circ \omega]$. Since $\omega \simeq \text{const}_{pt}$ $\implies p \circ \omega \simeq p \circ \text{const}_{pt} = \text{const}_{p(pt)}$, we have $\pi_1(Y)=1$. So $Y$ is also simply connected.

> c. Path connectedness

For any $a,b \in Y$, we have $a' , b' \in X$ such that $p(a') = a$ and $p(b')=b$. Since $X$ is path connected, there exists $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ with $\gamma(0) = a'$ and $\gamma(1) = b'$. Hence, we have $p \circ \gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ with $p \circ \gamma(0) = p(a') = a$ and $p \circ \gamma(1) = p(b') = b$. Since $p$ and $\gamma$ are continuous, so is their composition.

> d. Discreteness

I'm not really sure if I understood this one. Does it mean if the set $X$ has the discrete topology, then so must $Y$? If so, then let $a \in Y$. Since $X$ has the discrete topology, $p^{-1}(a)$ is open in $X$. By the definition of a quotient map, $a$ must be open in $Y$. Hence, $Y$ has the discrete topology.

Are my answers correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers **a**, **c**, and **d** are correct.  However, **b** is not.

A space is simply connected if it's fundamental group is trivial.  While you have correctly observed that a homotopy between paths passes to the quotient, it may be that certain open paths *become closed loops in the quotient*, hence generators in the fundamental group of the quotient space.

**Example.**  $X = [0, 1]$, $Y = S^1$, $p: X \to Y$ given by identifying the endpoints:
$$
p(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}.
$$
Now, $\pi_1(X) = 1$, but $\pi_1(Y) \cong \Bbb{Z}$, generated by the identity map.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but what is wrong with $\omega \simeq \text{const}_{pt}$ $\implies p \circ \omega \simeq p \circ \text{const}_{pt} = \text{const}_{p(pt)}$. Where exactly is the mistake? I thought it was a fact that $\omega \simeq \text{const}_{pt}$ $\implies p \circ \omega \simeq p \circ \text{const}_{pt}$, and the last equality just follows by the definition of a function (because $\text{const}_{pt}$ sends all points to a single point, and $p$ sends that point to exactly one point in Y), right?

Comment: That argument is sound.  That's what I was trying to say in the second paragraph ("...you have correctly observed that a homotopy between paths passes to the quotient...")  The problem is that some *loops* in $Y$ lift to (are the image of) certain *paths* in $X$ that do not close.  Hence, you can have a homotopy group generator in $Y$ that is not in the image of $p_* : \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$.